# PayPal Checkout - For updated PayPal checkout process do we need IPN?

Tags: paypal, checkout

As per the updated PayPal checkout process do we need IPN? I am referring checkout code form PayPal site.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the server-side integration: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/

Create two routes that return JSON, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'.

Pair your two routes with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

There is nothing this needs IPN for.